# Wordpress site bouncing to "localhost" URL w/ "It Works!"

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost

I've installed Wordpress into my site through my host Network Solutions. When I go to the URL where the blog should be hosted I see "It Works!" on the screen and nothing else. I'm not sure exactly what is going on or how to fix it.

Any help is much appreciated.

The site url is garrettminley.com/blog

Comment: What are you expecting to see? That's the default WordPress screen

Comment: Looks normal here; no mention of 'localhost' anywhere... perhaps you've got old DNS cached or something?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. This is what I see when attempting to access the site: http://imgur.com/bV7x2Jc

Comment: Thanks everyone! It looks like I just wasn't being patient enough to wait for things to update. Restarted my browser and everything seems to work fine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"It Works!" is its default HTML web page. Check your root directory and see if there is more than one file called "index". If you find two, then find which one has the HTML extension. Then just delete it.
Hope it works!